# entity retrieved from cache is not updated by the @Transactional in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-transactions

I am retrieving the User session from redis cache and making changes to the child entity
The changes made is not updated to the database with the help of the @Transactional Annotation

```
@Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateRating(@NonNull final String sessionId, @NonNull final UserRatingUpdateRequestDTO userRatingUpdateRequestDTO) {
        final UserSession fetchedSession = userSessionService.findUserSessionBySessionId(sessionId);
        final User user = fetchedSession.getUser();
        final LocalDate currentDate = DateTimeUtils.dateTimeInIST().toLocalDate();
        logger.info("Updating Rating for user : {}", user.getId());
        if (userRatingUpdateRequestDTO.isHasRated()) {
            user.getUserRating().setHasGivenRating(true);
        } else {
            int weeksToAdd = 5;
            user.getUserRating().setDate(currentDate.plusWeeks(weeksToAdd));
        }
        cacheInvalidatorService.evictUserSession(sessionId);
        cacheInvalidatorService.deleteUserDetails(user.getUsername());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("rating updated successfully");
    }

}
```

I tried to create a new transaction but the changes not reflecting into the database
I tried to use the Commit but that only be used inside the testing method

I want to update the database with the help of transaction annotation and with out saving the entity

or is it not possible